# IIS doesn't care about IIS Manager User

Tags: iis, iis-7, unauthorized, iis-manager

I'm running IIS 7.0 on a Windows 2008 R1 Server and want to setup IIS Manager Users. Due to some fact, every last try to access the site is rejected (HTTP Unauthorized).

The following additional IIS components are installed:

- Security\Basic Authentification
- Security\URL Authorisation
- Management Tools\IIS Management Console
- Management Tools\Management Service

Then I configured the Management Service to use Windows or IIS-Manager-User Credentials.
I also added some IIS-Manager-Users and activated them on my Website.

On the Authentification Settings Pane, I disabled anonymous access and enabled basic authentification.

As a result, when browsing the website, a password is now required. The thing is, I can access the page with Windows Credentials, **but not with the IIS Manager User Credentials**. In this case the result is always HTTP 401 - Unauthorized.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

IIS Manager Users are meant for administration of IIS (aka management of the sites/apps) and not for access the server at runtime (normal browsing of content).

Having said that, you can make that work if your scenario is to use the same users for potentially administration (like using WMSVC) and runtime and I wrote a blog about it on 2008 on how to set it up:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/26/using-iis-manager-users-in-your-application.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After enabling module overwriting, all I got is a `HTTP-Error 401.2 - Unauthorized`. I have anonymous and standard authentication disabled. Should this be working?